# How do I get microphone access in Google Chrome through getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microphone, getusermedia

I've tried many different types of Javascript code, and I've changed my microphone settings in Windows and in Chrome's settings, and nothing has worked. I've tried enabling "Web Audio Input" in `chrome://flags` but nothing works, at all. Does anyone have any suggestions? Camera access works and I can easily do HTML5 camera manipulation but any microphone tasks don't work.

The following JSFiddle doesn't work on my browser: http://jsfiddle.net/BWYu9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Give it a shot in the Canary build of Chrome. I think the ability to do this with an audio stream is pretty new - although for some reason I can't find a link to the Chromium issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Chrome Canary or perform the following steps:

1. open google.com
2. speak on microphone
3. if the answer is "cannot recognize speech it might be that your microphone is not recognized. (this will help to identify the source of the problem)

See the following link for this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226327

Answer (score 0):

I have found that many different problems can accrue with the microphone in the Google search window of chrome. The main problem I have found to be the most upsetting is after a Java up date I find it not working, but everything appears to be working fine with all my audio settings. My microphone levels are good in sound properties a for Google voice and video chat. but in the search bar of Google chrome the thing is still not working to solve the problem I discovered that resetting my Integrated Microphone Array to default had been canceled and after resitting it again to default this go the microphone to work.